# Reader writer solution using custom concurrent queue objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

IF we use custom concurrent queue to resolve this issue why we use dispatch_sync for reading and dispatch_async with barrier for writing?

Can't we use dispatch_async for reading as well ?

What is the difference here?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code and clarify where your question is.

Comment: I guess `dispatch barrier` will make sure data chunks come down to the file in the right order.

Comment: MY doubt is why we use dispatch_sync for read operation ? Why not dispatch_async

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101127/1271826. It’s Swift example, but all the basic principles are the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't we use dispatch_async for reading as well ?

No, `dispatch_async` says “dispatch this block of code to run asynchronously, but don’t wait for it to finish”. But the purpose of the “reader” is to provide thread-safe access to the value and return that value. If you use `dispatch_async`, you may return back from your “reader” method before the `dispatch_async` block has a chance to run.