# How to handle Race Condition Read/Write Problem in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

1. I have got a concurrent queue with dispatch barrier from **Raywenderlich** post **Example**

   private let concurrentPhotoQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.raywenderlich.GooglyPuff.photoQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

Where write operations is done in

```
func addPhoto(_ photo: Photo) {
  concurrentPhotoQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
    // 1
    guard let self = self else {
      return
    }

    // 2
    self.unsafePhotos.append(photo)

    // 3
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
      self?.postContentAddedNotification()
    }
  }
}
```

While read opeartion is done in

```
var photos: [Photo] {
  var photosCopy: [Photo]!

  // 1
  concurrentPhotoQueue.sync {

    // 2
    photosCopy = self.unsafePhotos
  }
  return photosCopy
}
```

As this will **resolve** Race Condition. Here why only **Write** operation is done with **barrier** and **Read** in **Sync**. Why is Read not done with barrier and write with sync ?. As with Sync Write, it will wait till it reads like a lock and while barrier Read it will only be read operation.

> set(10, forKey: "Number")
>
> print(object(forKey: "Number"))
>
> set(20, forKey: "Number")
>
> print(object(forKey: "Number"))

```
public func set(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        concurrentQueue.sync {
            self.dictionary[key] = value
        }
    }
    
    public func object(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        // returns after concurrentQueue is finished operation
        // beacuse concurrentQueue is run synchronously
        var result: Any?
        
        concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            result = self.dictionary[key]
        }
        
        return result
    }
```

With the flip behavior, I am getting nil both times, with barrier on Write it is giving 10 & 20 correct

Comment: The 2nd example in your revised question is an entirely different issue (and really should be a different question). The issue is not the choice of semaphore vs reader-writer, because any synchronization pattern would be sufficient (though semaphores would be my last choice). The issue is _what_ you synchronize. Specifically, the accessor-level synchronization (which you're doing here) is generally inadequate, you want to synchronize the whole “is there sufficient balance and, if so, deduct the amount from the balance” as a single task, not the individual read and write operations separately.

Comment: When one implements synchronization at the `get` and `set` accessor methods, that prevents memory faults and low-level data races, but is generally inadequate to achieve true thread-safety. Often you need a higher level of synchronization. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211849/1271826 for an example where even the trivial incrementing of an integer is not-thread-safe, and we need a higher level of abstraction in our synchronization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You ask:

> Why is Read not done with barrier ... ?.

In this reader-writer pattern, you don’t use barrier with “read” operations because reads *are* allowed to happen concurrently with respect to other “reads”, without impacting thread-safety. It’s the whole motivating idea behind reader-writer pattern, to allow concurrent reads.

So, you *could* use barrier with “reads” (it would still be thread-safe), but it would unnecessarily negatively impact performance if multiple “read” requests happened to be called at the same time. If two “read” operations can happen concurrently with respect to each other, why not let them? Don’t use barriers (reducing performance) unless you absolutely need to.

Bottom line, only “writes” need to happen with barrier (ensuring that they’re not done concurrently with respect to any “reads” or “writes”). But no barrier is needed (or desired) for “reads”.

> [Why not] ... write with sync?

You *could* “write” with `sync`, but, again, why would you? It would only degrade performance. Let’s imagine that you had some reads that were not yet done and you dispatched a “write” with a barrier. The dispatch queue will ensure for us that a “write” dispatched with a barrier won’t happen concurrently with respect to any other “reads” or “writes”, so why should the code that dispatched that “write” sit there and wait for the “write” to finish?

Using `sync` for writes would only negatively impact performance, and offers no benefit. The question is not “why not write with `sync`?” but rather “why would you *want* to write with `sync`?” And the answer to that latter question is, you don’t want to wait unnecessarily. Sure, you have to wait for “reads”, but not “writes”.

You mention:

> With the flip behavior, I am getting `nil` ...

Yep, so lets consider your hypothetical “read” operation with `async`:

```
public func object(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
    var result: Any?

    concurrentQueue.async {
        result = self.dictionary[key]
    }

    return result
}
```

This effective says “set up a variable called `result`, dispatch task to retrieve it *asynchronously,* but don’t wait for the read to finish before returning whatever `result` currently contained (i.e., `nil`).”

You can see why reads must happen *synchronously*, because you obviously can’t return a value before you update the variable!

---

So, reworking your latter example, you read synchronously without barrier, but write asynchronously with barrier:

```
public func object(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
    return concurrentQueue.sync {
        self.dictionary[key]
    }
}

public func set(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
    concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        self.dictionary[key] = value
    }
}
```

Note, because `sync` method in the “read” operation will return whatever the closure returns, you can simplify the code quite a bit, as shown above.

Or, personally, rather than `object(forKey:)` and `set(_:forKey:)`, I’d just write my own [subscript operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html):

```
public subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
    get {
        concurrentQueue.sync { 
            dictionary[key] 
        } 
    }

    set { 
        concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.dictionary[key] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```
store["Number"] = 10
print(store["Number"])
store["Number"] = 20
print(store["Number"])
```

---

Note, if you find this reader-writer pattern too complicated, note that you could just use a serial queue (which is like using a barrier for both “reads” and “writes”). You’d still probably do `sync` “reads” and `async` “writes”. That works, too. But in environments with high contention “reads”, it’s just a tad less efficient than the above reader-writer pattern.

Comment: I understood why read is sync because I can't return value before reading so wait is required but for write why its async with barrier any how we are waiting with flag ?

Comment: Let’s tackle this one step at a time. Why is write async? Like you said, with read, you do it synchronously because you have to wait for the result to be returned. So in write, where we don’t need to return anything, we can therefore no longer need to wait for the dispatched block to finish, which means that we can do it asynchronously, which avoids blocking the caller’s thread during writes. Why do write with barrier? Because we need to make sure that the write does not happen concurrently with anything else on that queue, and that’s what barriers do. But we don’t wait for writes.

Comment: ok got it and for read we are not using "barrier" for concurrency but any how we are using sync which will block the queue like If two “read” operations can happen concurrently with respect to each other any how second need to start after 1 which will impact performance

Comment: Correct, reads can enjoy concurrency (no barrier), but calling thread must wait (sync), but writes can not be concurrent (thus, the barrier), but calling thread doesn’t have to wait (hence async).

Comment: edited question for different ways to solve race condition. Is semaphore same as dispatch barrier ?

Comment: @salmansiddiqui E.g. in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211849/1271826 I benchmarked a bunch of different synchronization mechanisms in Swift.

Comment: @salmansiddiqui - So you substantively change the question 2½ years later and then unaccept my answer? Lol. You should have just posted a new question if wanted to ask about other synchronization mechanisms. Or researched it first; there are lots of existing answers (see above) comparing the different synchronization methods. In short, one technically can use semaphores, but it’s the last tool we would reach for. `NSLock` is simple and performant. Unfair locks can be useful where performance is critical, but it’s a little cumbersome and its overkill in most situations.

Comment: with above answer I tried to solve different  problem you can see in edited question its giving incorrect result that's the reason I unaccepted the  answer.

Comment: @Rob out of curiosity, why is the queue needed at all for the read operation. If concurrent reads can happen, does it need to be wrapped in its own dispatch queue?

Comment: @Dr.Mr.Uncle - Because reads can only happen concurrently only with respect to other reads. But they cannot be performed concurrently with writes. So concurrent queue allows the reads to happen concurrently, with the exception of writes, which is why we use barrier for writes.

Comment: Thank you Rob! Very helpful explanation